# What content information has been prescribed under s5(1)(a) PEA1977?

Tags: england-and-wales, eviction, notice

Subsection 5(1)(a) Protection from Eviction Act 1977 requires notices to quit to contain such information as may be prescribed. What prescriptions have been made under this provision, and how might one have gone about finding out such information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UKSI 1988/2201](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1988/2201/made) was made under the powers conferred by PEA1977